# React Native - Resize Image component

Tags: css, react-native, image, jsx, image-resizing

I have one app in React Native and I'm trying to introduce an image in my app, but the image it's to big and the image takes up the entire screen. To fix that, I tried

```
imagem:{
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
```

The image itself is at a good size, but the component it's to larger, so it's harder to see the other components.

The full script is here:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {  
const moedas = [
    require('./imagens/m1.png'),
    require('./imagens/m5.png'),
    require('./imagens/m1.png'),
    require('./imagens/m2.png'),
    require('./imagens/m3.png'),
    require('./imagens/m4.png'),
    require('./imagens/m5.png'),
    require('./imagens/m6.png'),
    require('./imagens/m7.png'),
    require('./imagens/m8.png'),
  ]

  let iMoeda = 0
  const maxGiros = 20

  const [moedaAtual,setMoedaAtual] = useState(moedas[iMoeda])

  async function espera(tmp) {
    function tempo(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms))
    }
    await tempo(tmp)
  }

  async function girarMoeda() {
    
  }  
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={estilos.container}>
      <View>
        <Text>Cara ou Coroa</Text>
        <Image style={estilos.imagem} source={moedaAtual}/>
        <Button
          title='Girar'
          onPress={()=>{}}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const estilos = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imagem:{
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can remove the flex: 1 property from the estilos.imagem**

```
const estilos = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imagem:{
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't see the component and the image

Answer (score 0):

Set `width` to 100% and `height` to fixed size (to leave space for other components) and then either contain or cover for `resizeMode` to get the desired result.

```
<Image
  style={{ width: '100%', height: 400, resizeMode: 'cover' }}
  source={{
    uri: 'https://picsum.photos/1920/1080',
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried your code and now I can't see the image, but the component itself was reduce